# Trying to convert MS Access query to SQL Server view but getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

It's hard to convert this code manually for me.

```
SELECT 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Kampanya Adı], DepolarTbl.[BM Adı], 
    DepolarTbl.[Müşteri Adı], DepolarTbl.[BM Adı], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.KOD, Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[DEPO ADI], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[ECZANE GLN KODU], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[ECZANE ADI], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Düzeltilmiş Ürün Adı] AS [Ürün Adı], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[SATIŞ ADET], 
    IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF]), IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl]![BMMF]), [Birlesmis_Data_Urun].[MF ADET], [KampanyaDetayTbl]![BMMF]),[KampanyaDetayTbl]![KMMF]) AS SonucMF, 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[MF ADET] AS [Istenen MF], 
    IIf([SonucMF]=[Istenen MF],"Yok","Var") AS Duzenleme, 
    [Fiyat] * ([Istenen MF] - [SonucMF]) AS Tutar
FROM 
    ((Birlesmis_Data_Urun 
LEFT JOIN 
    KampanyaDetayTbl ON Birlesmis_Data_Urun.ID = KampanyaDetayTbl.MFID)  
INNER JOIN 
    DepolarTbl ON Birlesmis_Data_Urun.KOD = DepolarTbl.KOD) 
LEFT JOIN 
    UrunFiyatTbl ON (Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Düzeltilmiş Ürün Adı] = UrunFiyatTbl.UrunAdi) AND (Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Kampanya Adı] = UrunFiyatTbl.KampanyaAdi);
```

Things I did :

1. Replace `!` with `.`
2. Replace `IsNull` with  = `' '` For example `IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl]![BMMF]),)` -> `IIf([KampanyaDetayTbl].[BMMF]=' ',)`
3. Replace `"` with `'`
4. Delete `;`

And I got this error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'SonucMF'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Istenen MF'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Istenen MF'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'SonucMF'.

How can convert this query to a SQL Server view ?

Comment: YOU can't reference aliased columns a second time in the same query

Comment: Is there a solution for this ? This works in Ms Access so I have to find a way. I think I can use aliased column after "where" but I guess I can't use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed the referance aliases with [tablename].[columnname]  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )` to

```
Case when condition then value_if_true else value_if_false end
```

Comment: IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF],0), IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl].[BMMF],0), [Birlesmis_Data_Urun].[MF ADET], [KampanyaDetayTbl].[BMMF]),[KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF]) AS SonucMF how can I replace iif here ?